# Create rows of 10 numbers out of an array with N random numbers

Tags: java, arrays, random

I am trying to create rows with 10 numbers out of an array with N random numbers that are sorted in increasing order. I have managed to create an array with N random numbers and I have also sorted them, but I don't know how to print them in rows of 10 numbers. Any help would be appreciated.

Here's my code for the N random numbers:

```
public class Mergesort {

    private static double[] merge(double[] a, double[] b) {
        double[] c = new double[a.length + b.length];
        int i = 0, j = 0;
        for (int k = 0; k < c.length; k++) {
            if      (i >= a.length) c[k] = b[j++];
            else if (j >= b.length) c[k] = a[i++];
            else if (a[i] <= b[j])  c[k] = a[i++];
            else                    c[k] = b[j++];
        }
        return c;
    }

    public static double[] mergesort(double[] input) {
        int N = input.length;
        if (N <= 1) return input;
        double[] a = new double[N/2];
        double[] b = new double[N - N/2];
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
            a[i] = input[i];
        for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++)
            b[i] = input[i + N/2];
        return merge(mergesort(a), mergesort(b));
    }


   /***************************************************************************
    *  Check if array is sorted - useful for debugging.
    ***************************************************************************/
    private static boolean isSorted(double[] a) {
        for (int i = 1; i < a.length; i++)
            if (a[i] < a[i-1]) return false;
        return true;
    }



    // generate N real numbers between 0 and 1, and mergesort them
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int N = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        double[] a = new double[N];
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            a[i] = (int)(Math.random() * 100 + 1);
        a = mergesort(a);
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            StdOut.println(a[i]);

        StdOut.println(isSorted(a));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

simply with a Loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i<array.length;i++){ 
    System.out.print(array[i]);
    if (i%10 == 9) { // if i modulo 10 is 9 add an linebreak
       System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: @AtalAtmar Have changed my answer. please review

Comment: I have one last question. My output contains whole numbers only. How do I remove the .0 behind every number?

Comment: @AtalAtmar Can you shou me the result and the expected result?

Comment: For example, if I put in 10 for N, the result looks like this: 7.0 11.0 13.0 36.0 49.0 51.0 55.0 57.0 94.0. It should be like this: 7 11 13 36 49 51 55 57 94.

Comment: @AtalAtmar it is because you have a double as data type. you can cast it to an int and the decimal part will go away: `System.out.print((int)array[i]+" ");`

Comment: @AtalAtmar you are welcome. Feel free to upvote and/or accept my answer

Answer (score 0):

Use `System.out.print()` instead of `System.out.println()`.

`System.out.println()` will automatically add "\n" in the end of your line while the `System.out.print()` won't.